# How to share one classpath for multiple jar files

Tags: java, maven, jar, classloader

Is it possible to point some **.jar** file classpath to a currently executing **.jar** file classpath?  I know sounds like crazy but i recently encounter a situation like above.My requirement was that i have a maven project that fetching some necessary jar files from maven nexus run time.Also i have a another maven project i include that project as a maven dependency into current project.so all together i have  **two jar** files.one as dependency and one is as a fetching from maven nexus.

When i am executing what i do is reading nexus jar file as a input stream and access classes via URLClassLoader.

```
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader("Nexus URL path to .jar");
Class c = ucl.loadClass(".classfile");
```

This load and execute successfully.While executing some of classes from nexus jar it access my other jar dependency classes.(Eg:try to read a file via utility class that in other jar but resource file is in my nexus jar).so i got `NoClassDefFoundError`.The reason for that was that utility class load it class path as where it resides(pointed to my current project `src/class`) and try to search resource file in there.But actual resource files contains in nexus jar class path.so my execution break.

How can i point dependency jar classpath into the Nexus jar class path?Please let me know your ideas.

Comment: Take a look at [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) and put into one of your projects. That can execute the project and put the dependencies on the classpath.

Comment: @ khmarbaise in my case nexus jar will be extracted dynamic location per execution.so is it possible to configure or it can be done via custom class loader?